# JSF 2.2 portlet fileupload in Websphere Portal 8.5

Tags: jsf-2.2, websphere-portal

I'm working now at JSF 2.2 portlet project for WebSphere 8.5 using Primefaces 5.2. This time I have a problem with primefaces fileupload component. After searching for solution I found that the primefaces fileupload component doesn't work in WebSphere Portal, because IBM jsf portlet bridge doesn't support file uploading.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?
I cannot change my project to use another framework, because the 95% of project already is done and I didn't know about this problem at the beginning of project.
If it is not possible, then is there any way to uploading a file within my project?
If it is possible, please, give me solution preferably with detailed documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We aren't a coding service. We're glad to help you figure out a problem, though. I'd recommend reading [ask] and reformatting your question along the lines of: "I am trying to get Primefaces to upload files in WebSphere Portal. Here's what I've tried already..."

Comment: Ohhh, I'm very sorry for my bad english. And I don't want you to write the project for me. I simply wanted to ask is there any way to upload a files in JSF porlet in WebSphere Portal or is it possible to make to work the Primefaces fileupload component. Anyway thank you for your reply!

Comment: @RomaR5, can you try to upload a file like in [this guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0807_abbass/0807_abbass.html)? I think you should be able to write the html and java necessary to do this in JSF, however it will not use Primefaces for that aspect. Otherwise, you can look into the fix we did in the [Liferay Faces Bridge for this issue with Primefaces](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces/compare/8790c7ba9b200470358b071d0da3fee6b39bc068...444151e7d0869fa474f592108e2cab7cd8921bba).

Comment: @ stiemannkj1, thank you. I will try monday and will write about the results.